# what's wrong with this approach?

Tags: java, string, coding-style, constants

A new Code Review process has been put in place and now my team must not ever declare a string as a local variable, or the commit won't pass the code review. We are now to use constants instead.

So this is absolutely not allowed, even if we're dead sure the string will never be used in any other place

```
String operationId = "create";
```

This is what should be used instead:

```
private static final String OPERATION_ID = "create";
```

While I totally agree to use constants for strings that appears +2 times in the code ... I just find it overkill to completely not have the ability to declare a string in place if it's used only once.

Just to make sure it's clear, all the following are **NOT ALLOWED under any circumstances:**

- `String div = "div1";`
- `Catch(Exception ex){ LOGGER.log("csv file is corrupt") }`
- String concatenation `String str = "something ...." + someVar + "something"` ... we are to replace `someVar` with `%s`, declare whole thing as a global string, and then later use `String.format(....)`
- `if( name.equals("Audi" ){....}`
- `String value = map.get("key")`

Any ideas guys ? I want some strong arguments. I'm ready to embrace any stand that's backed by a good argument.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe more of a code review question?

Comment: Are you still allowed to interact with a `List<String>`? I.e. `String elm0 = lst.get(0)`?

Comment: @Mshnik I don't see how that's related; there's no immediate string there.

Comment: We're not even supposed to define strings as constants.  They're all externalized into properties files.  (Which, while often annoying, does make localization much easier).

Comment: @DaveNewton you're correct (and hence it isn't even possible to replace it as a constant), but it is declaring a String as a local variable nonetheless

Comment: @azurefrog: There's a big difference between strings used as identifiers or markup, and strings used as user-facing text.  Some static checkers will enforce that the former have an annotation or comment associated with it.

Comment: Where/how the string is declared *does* make a difference. Personally I've never found a reason to make a string a final constant until it's used twice, although I'm generally twitchy around magic numbers and almost always avoid them. Interpolation is usually better than concatenation, though.

Comment: The point is to get rid of magic strings. Any string hardcoded anywhere is a magic string and makes testing harder. You might have to know what the magic strings are and that requires a unit tester to know the internal state of the class. Defining stuff as constants is better. Even better I think is to externalize every hard code and inject into the classes.

Comment: @Mshnik AFAICT the issue is around string literals, not string variables. It doesn't even seem like a reasonable thing to consider, not being able to use a local string reference.

Comment: Personally I think it's insane to extend this requirement to logging.  Even if you have a requirement for localized log files, you would key the property by a string, which you would then have to make a constant?

Comment: We're talking about strings that will never end up in the UI ... like when you log an exception, or when you send something to the database,, and other stuff that only the developers will see.
So let's not talk about localization here !

Comment: @MarkPeters I never said my current employer isn't insane ;-). But even for error logging, we have to do a look-up of an error message by exception type, and then write said message to a log file, and also forward it to a centralized error management service.

Comment: It's not so much that I agree that it's a good practice, so much as I wanted to point out that restrictions like the OP is talking about aren't all that uncommon...

Answer (score 0):

First, let's throw out your assumption: There's nothing inherently *wrong* with the approach described.

It's not about strings being used in more than one place, it's about constants being easy to find and documented, and your code being *consistent*.

```
private static final String OPERATION_ID = "create";
```

Really, this isn't used *anywhere* else? Nothing would break if I changed this to the string "beetlejuice"? If something would break, then something else is using this constant... If the "something else" happens to be a codebase in a different language, and that's why they don't share string constants-- that's the exception, not the rule. Consistency!

---

That said, there are a few things I would standardize in a slightly different manner, but I would still standardize them nonetheless:

I would suggest allowing string literals in the constructors of enums:

```
public enum Operation {
    CREATE("create"),
    ...
}
```

because here, the enum is the constant that is being referenced in the code, not the string literal. Declaring the constant as an enum or as a `private static final String` are equivalent to me, and there's no need to do both.

Additionally, I would not use this pattern anywhere that it breaks your IDE's ability to warn you about missing strings-- For example, looking up strings from .properties files. Many IDEs will give you proper warnings when you look up a key in a .properties file that doesn't exist, but the extra level of indirection might break that depending upon how smart your IDE is.

```
Catch(Exception ex){ LOGGER.log("csv file is corrupt") }
```

This to me is a bit of a gray area - Is this an internal-only message? Are the logs only ever seen by you, the developer, or are they for a user's benefit too?

If it's only for developers of the application These probably don't need to be localized.

If you do expect the user to view the logs, then they should be externalized into a .properties file.

Answer (score 0):

It is good coding style to define a constant for a value/literal when the value/literal is used multiple times.

The imposed coding style forces you to use a constant for **every** string literal.

The **good** effect of that coding style is: All string literals which really should be declared as constants are now declared as constants.

The **bad** implication of that coding style is: You - the developers - are not able to decide if a string literal should be defined as constant or not. This is a heavy punch.

Therefore you should raise your concerns that the good intention of the coding style does not compensate for the mistrust in your developer qualitites.